# How to extract key and value pairs and store them in Object Store V2 Mule 2.0

Tags: mule, dataweave, mule4, anypoint-platform

I have a requirement to iterate the below input payload and store all the EMPNAME as key and EMPID as value in Object store.

```
{
    "application": "salesforce",
    "payload": [
        {
            "EMPLASTNAME": "Jane",
            "EMPFIRSTNAME": "Adams",
            "EMPEMAIL": "Adams456@isasnap.com",
            "EMPID": 12345,
            "EMPNAME": "e76543"
        },
        {
            "EMPLASTNAME": "Stella",
            "EMPFIRSTNAME": "Benedict",
            "EMPEMAIL": "Benedict564@isasnap.com",
            "EMPID": 67896,
            "EMPNAME": "e34896"
        },
        {
            "EMPLASTNAME": "Cooper",
            "EMPFIRSTNAME": "Jake",
            "EMPEMAIL": "Cooper133@isasnap.com",
            "EMPID": 98765,
            "EMPNAME": "e11356"
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried extracting the key and value pairs using the below DW code

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
((payload.payload map {
($.EMPNAME): $.EMPID
}))
```

output:

```
[
  {
    "e76543": 12345
  },
  {
    "e34896": 67896
  },
  {
    "e11356": 98765
  }
]
```

After this I am not able to proceed on how to put these values into Object Store (v2) as key value pairs.

I am not sure if the above DW is right way to extract the key pairs which can be used further for storing in object Store.

For example, In Object Store the key should be e76543 and value should be 12345.

Also is there a way to store the above response to a variable and update Object store in a single go

Thanks in advance

Comment: The title is misleading, there was a mule 2 long ago but the current version is mule 4.  I suggest "mule object store", it doesn't matter if you are using OSv2 or just any mule object store for the question

Comment: Yes, "Storing multiple entries in Mule Object Store" is a better title for this

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to transform that original payload. Using the Foreach Scope you can select the collection to iterate inside the payload, then use the ObjectStore connector Store operation.

Example:

```xml
<foreach collection="#[payload.payload]">
    <os:store key="#[payload.EMPNAME]">
        <os:value>#[payload.EMPID]</os:value>
    </os:store>
</foreach>
```

As you can see in the [documentation of the Object Store connector](https://docs.mulesoft.com/object-store-connector/latest/object-store-connector-reference#operations) there is no store all keys operation.

Comment: @Sunny85 Just be careful with the rate limit. The base subscription offers only 10 TPS which can easily exceed in your scenario. Check if you account has the premium ad-on for 100 TPS. [Official Doc Reference](https://docs.mulesoft.com/object-store/osv2-faq#what-are-the-limits-on-an-object-store)

Comment: Thanks Aled, Harshank, I will check on TPS.

Comment: @Sunny85 if the answer is what you expect and helped then mark this as your answer so no one comes in here to try to answer something that was already answered